# Image not showing after changing Wordpress website domain

Tags: wordpress, url, dns, media

I changed my website`s domain and it works correctly. but any of image in my website not loading now. I changed post links using search & replace plugin but there is no result. 
Even if i upload new image it does not show up! 
Any idea what should I do?
p.s. this is my website address: www.tarkhisad.com
[here is a screen shot of my library](https://i.stack.imgur.com/5t9m4.png)

Comment: Check file ownership and permissions

Comment: Hi. thanks for your respond. funny thing is I already checked upload folder permissions. and i was on 755. but I just checked it and set it to 777 then set it back to 755 and it works! anyway thank you